# Dropping malformed lines while reading csv file in Pyspark causing job failure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a large csv dataset into PySpark. Some of the data is malformed and doesn't comply with the schema I've specified.

I am trying to drop such malformed rows from the dataframe :

```
df_raw=spark.read\
   .format("org.apache.spark.csv") \
   .option("header","true")\
   .option("quote",'"') \
   .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
   .schema(df_schema) \
   .csv(input_file)
```

However, it seems to kill the job on the executor whenever a malformed line is encountered:

```
16/11/04 11:24:47 WARN CSVRelation: Dropping malformed line: 
888800017810876000, 10.61,D,10792516955,,,aa999,,"19 Y1U ""R""",EO,,
"10 Y1U ""R""   AI2, YT IA", XXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ,
63.0, going great, 2016-05-17,436,2016-05-17,SOMECODE

16/11/04 11:28:14 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.net.SocketException: socket already closed
```

It seems to be causing a memory spike. Can anyone explain what's going on and suggest a possible workaround ?